# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" - but nothing is null?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

Yeah, you probably think; "God, another one?".

Yes, another one.

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I've been working with EF6 lately and after developing for some time, I found that a little bit more optimization was needed. Alot has been reworked without problems, but it seems I can't figure out this one.

In my application I've been using this piece of pseudo code to get items from the database.

```
DbContext context = new DbContext();

public IEnumerable<string> GetExistingNames(IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    foreach(string name in names)
    {
        string existingName = context.Names.Where(n => n.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
        if(existingName == null) continue;
        yield return existingName;
    }
}
```

Note that the `DbContext` is only there for clarification. It gets disposed when it's needed.

This approach "works" but it would mean that if I had, say, 20 names to look up, I would hit the database for about 20 times. Ouch!

Therefore I started looking for a way to implement a single query. I've found a way, but it's not really working as it should. This is my current approach;

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetExistingNames(ICollection<string> names)
{
    IQueryable<Names> query = context.Names.Where(n => names.Contains(n.Name));
    if(query == null) yield break;
    foreach(var name in query)
    {
        yield return name.Name;
    }
}
```

This should, to my knowledge, translate in `SELECT ... FROM Names WHERE ... IN (...)`. However, my application crashes at `foreach(var name in query)` as soon as it hits `name`, throwing the feared `NullReferenceException`.
It does, however, pass `if(query == null)`, meaning the query is not null. At this point, I was confused. How can it not be null, but still throw this error?

I was not sure if the query gets executed if I try to access it with this approach. Therefore, I tried to create a list from the query using `ToList()`, but this throws the same exception upon creating the list.

It seems like everytime I make a call to `query`, it gives me a `NullReferenceException`. However, it still passes `if(query == null)`. So, my question is;

**Why is it passing the test, but is it not accessible? Did I misinterpret `IQueryable<>`? And if I did misinterpret it, how should it be done properly?**

**EDIT**

I have debugged before posting. I know for sure that;

- `names` is not null.
- `context` is not null.

Code calling the function:

```
//A wrapper for the DbContext. This is only used for some methods
//which require the DbContext
DbContextWrapper wrapper = new DbContextWrapper();

public void ProcessNames(List<string> inputNames)
{
    //...

    foreach(string existingName in wrapper.GetExistingNames(inputNames))
    {
        //Do something with the names
    }

    //...
}
```

**EDIT 2**

After some more debugging, I found that the query being created is somewhat different. It is supposed to be;

```
SELECT `Extent1`.`Name` 
FROM `Names` AS `Extent1` 
WHERE (`Extent1`.`Name` IN ( @gp1,@gp2))
```

However, I get this;

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<MyDbContext.Names>
```

As the actual query.

The stack trace;

```
at MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.Visit(DbPropertyExpression expression)
at MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.Visit(DbInExpression expression)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbInExpression.Accept[TResultType](DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor)
at MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitBinaryExpression(DbExpression left, DbExpression right, String op)
at MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.Visit(DbAndExpression expression)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbAndExpression.Accept[TResultType](DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor)
at MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbFilterExpression expression)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbFilterExpression.Accept[TResultType](DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor)
at MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)
at MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)
at MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbProjectExpression expression)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbProjectExpression.Accept[TResultType](DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor)
at MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.GenerateSQL(DbCommandTree tree)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.CreateCommandDefinition(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Span span, IEnumerable`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
at MyNameSpace.DbContextWrapper.<GetExistingNames>d__1b.MoveNext() in c:~omitted~\DbContextWrapper.cs:line 70
at MyNameSpace.NameProcessor.ProcessNames(List<string> inputNames) in c:~omitted~\NameProcessor.cs:line 60
```

Comment: The `query` item may not be null, but the `foreach` builds an iterator around it. Basically, more code is running in the background that you are not stepping into, and that code is whatever the implementation of `query` (`IQueryable<T>`) is - which is the EF stuff.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I get the point where the `foreach` tries to create an iterator and call `MoveNext()`, which is prone to the NullRef if `query` is null - but it passes the `if`!

Comment: Does `names` contain a reference? Are you sure `context` contains a reference? Are any of the items in `names` `null` perhaps? And note that just saying "Yes, I know, nullrefereneexception, this is different though" doesn't make it different. All the questions around this are different, but the solution is always the same, debug, debug, debug. I fail to see anything new here.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen `names` is definitely not null, neither is `context`. I have, of course, debugged before posting here. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: Can you show the code calling the function? And where does `context` come from? Can you show the full code here? Since you're using `IEnumerable<string>` as a result, can you show the loop using the code alongside the code disposing of `context`?

Comment: Try add `IEnumerator<Names> test = query.GetEnumerator();` and check `test`. Is it null?

Comment: To be clear `query` will never be null even if your where clause would return no records. It is dificult to tell WHAT exactly is null but why don't you change the entire method to `return context.Where(n => names.Contains(n)).Select(x => x.Name)`

Comment: @Reniuz The `Enumerator` actually gets created, but it is not null. The `Current` is null, however. Does checking on `Current` solve my problem or is it more of a workaround?

Comment: How can it be `null`? is `IQueryable<Names>`, that is `context.Names` returning a collection containing a `null` reference? That seems odd.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen upon calling something on it, yes. Only thing that does get called is `GetEnumerator()` atm.

Comment: No, don't check Current. Can you post full stacktrace?

Comment: @DionV. Testing `query` for null is just testing the gate to a lot of code behind it. Creating the iterator unlocks the code that powers it. A `foreach` is great a hiding a lot of code, this is where the null ref is originating from.

Comment: @DionV. If `Current` property of the enumerator is null at some point there's no wonder you get `NullReferenceException` - the `Contains` method tries to get value of the `Name` property of non-existent object (the predicate is actually evaluated in the `MoveNext()` method of the enumerator). A simple `context.Names.OfType<Names>()` will filter out those null references. Interesting question however is WHY are there nulls in the collection...

Comment: @DionV. Unless you're talking about `Current` being null BEFORE the first call to `MoveNext()` - in that case it's expected.

Comment: @Grx70, yes, it is null before entering `foreach` and thus calling `MoveNext`.

Comment: So how about stacktrace?

Comment: @Reniuz I'm sorry, read over it, but I doubt it will help. You can see from where it is called in the edited part of my question.

Comment: Well maybe it will show where deeper in the code (that @AdamHouldsworth was talking about) error occurred.

Comment: `throwing the feared NullReferenceException` There's nothing feared about it. It's a common problem with a common solution: find what's null and then make sure it gets initialized before calling methods on it. The code that throws the NullReferenceException may not be in your own code, but it may be caused by something you do in your code. Step through the code (even the code that isn't yours) and figure out what's null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you posted stacktrace I spotted that you using MySQL and so my guess is that you hit this bug: [Exception when using IEnumera.Contains(model.property) in Where predicate](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73643)

So solution would be to ensure you have versions of MySQL Connector/NET 6.7.6 / 6.8.4 / 6.9.5 and newer.
Or try to use `Any` method instead of `Contains`.

P.s. This bug report came from this post by Alnedru: [Int[].Contains doesn't work in EF6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028973/int-contains-doesnt-work-in-ef6?rq=1)

Comment: This is actually a nice one, I didn't find it. I am using Connector/NET 6.9.3, so I guess it doesn't contain this bugfix?

Comment: As I understand you need to update it at least to 6.9.5 to get the fix.

Comment: By the way I searched by first stack trace entries and came up to the SO question I added to my answer. So as you can see stack trace helps ;)

Comment: I was away from work yesterday, but I tested it right away this morning and the upgrade worked like a charm. Thanks alot!

Comment: Good to hear that! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your null check on query will never fail, because it's returning the IQueryable object (that is, the query being built). You've instantiated it and started building a query, so it will always pass.

To be clear - IQueryable is roughly equivalent to a string containing the ADO.Net Select statement. It is not, inherently, the actual data.

This doesn't explain why it's throwing a null exception, but it *does* explain why the null check passes, and the foreach could still fail.

EDIT: When attempting to duplicate this, I found that I get an exception when using the below code:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetExistingNames(ICollection<string> names)
{
    IQueryable<Names> query = Names.Where(n => names.Contains(n.Name));
    if (query == null) yield break;
    foreach (var name in query)
    {
        yield return name.Name;
    }
}
```

It wasn't a `NullReferenceException`, but a `NotSupportedException`, as ICollections `Contains` has no supported translation to SQL. Switching the parameter to `List` caused the problem to disappear:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetExistingNames(List<string> names)
```

Or you can convert it to a list on the fly:

```
IQueryable<Names> query = Names.Where(n => names.ToList().Contains(n.Name));
```

Comment: Enumerating a `IQueryable<>` will indeed hit the database. And while `IQueryable<>` is the *recipe for how to obtain the data*, enumerating over it, and thus producing an `IEnumerator<>` object will fetch the data.

Comment: *I was not sure if the query gets executed if I try to access it with this approach. Therefore, I tried to create a list from the query using ToList(), but this throws the same exception upon creating the list* - The call of `ToList()` will result in a `NullReferenceException`, unfortunately.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Fair point - I was going on memory before, I've removed that part of my answer.

Comment: It does indeed answer *Why is it passing the test, but is it not accessible?*, therefore I've upvoted it. It does however not solve my problem and therefore I cannot mark it as answered.

Comment: @DionV. I'm a bit stumped on that, although I did find a different exception when using ICollection. Updated my answer.

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix I saw that, and I tried the same but it's still throwing the same error. I think `names` already was a `List<string>` since I pass it through in the method above (which you can see in the edit in my post). Still stuck on the same error though...

Comment: @DionV. Sounds like a potential data issue then, I'm stumped unless you can get together a standalone repro that we can use to get it throwing on our side. We'd probably need an example of the full table structure and sample data, etc. Hopefully someone better than I will see your issue without that.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you just add an extension method to alleviate the stress this brings you.
try this piece of code

```
namespace HelperExtensionMethods
{
    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static string UpdateNullString(this string testNullstring)
        {
            if (TestNullstring == null)
                return "";
            return Testullstring;
        }
    }
}
```

and then call it like so

```
using HelperExtesionMethods
DbContext context = new DbContext();

public IEnumerable<string> GetExistingNames(ICollection<string> names)
{
    IQueryable<Names> query = context.Names.Where(n => names.UpdateNullString().Contains(n.Name.UpdateNullString()));
    if(query == null) yield break;
    foreach(var name in query)
    {
        yield return name.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) This question is already answered a long time ago and 2) You can't just create an extension for `string` and expect EntityFramework to create a query out of it. Have you tried to run this code by yourself? Just because it compiles doesn't mean it works. 3) The problem was not the `string` being null, but the `query` object.